# Changing default workspace name in R on Mac (and Linux)

Tags: r

I use R on both Mac and Linux operating systems and generally run it from the command line. There is one behaviour that I find completely frustrating and that is the tendency for R to save the default workspace with the name ".RData" – which is invisible on both Mac and Linux.

I've been caught out a few times with this issue. I've saved a workspace with a specific name such as:

```
save.image(file="myRData.RData")   # which is visible in the working directory
```

Then I've made some changes to the workspace and, when I quit R, the terminal asks whether I want to save the workspace. I type 'Y', naturally assuming that any changes will be saved in the workspace created above. But that does not happen. Instead, R creates a new workspace called .RData – which is invisible – and saves the data there.

So, when I come to use the data again and I load the workspace using:

```
load("myRData.RData")
```

I actually end up opening an old version of the data.

Is there a why to change the name of the default workspace name from .RData to something that is visible (e.g. RData.RData), perhaps using the .Rprofile configuration file?

Comment: Surely the easy fix is to configure your operating system to not hide the file from you? [Here's a search of how to do it on OSX](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=osx%20show%20hidden%20files). In general, it's not a great practice to mix and match dependencies on manual (or scripted) saves and auto save-on-close load-on-open images.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That would indeed make the .RData files visible but it would also make all the other invisible system files visible as well – and navigating through folders containing lots of invisible files is even more of a pain. I suppose the problem is that we've been conditioned to be able to open a file, make changes and when we hit "save", the changes are saved back to the document that was opened.

Comment: You could define `.First` and `.Last` functions in your `.Rprofile`. A better approach is to save your data loading and processing into an actual reproducible script you can re-run. If you use RMarkdown, you can set caching options if it's worth it. If you've graduated to writing files, though, you're using a text editor (even if just built-in vi or TextEdit), so you might as well get a decent one. RStudio is the obvious choice (technically it's an IDE, but a very lightweight one) which has a preference for this issue anyway, but there are lots of candidates depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks alistaire. When you talk about saving data loading and processing into a reproducible script, are you suggesting that it's better to not to save workspaces at all but, instead, re-run all relevant commands from a saved script each time? I'll check our R Studio – it's been on my to-do list for a while but this might be just the push I need.